# i have problem when upgrade kali linux 2020

Tags: apt, package-management, kali-linux

I ran `apt-get upgrade` and got:

```
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
text-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message “Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)” indicates a problem with the package installer. This can happen after a failed software installation, or if the installer becomes corrupted.

The key phrase in this error is /usr/bin/dpkg. This refers to the dpkg package installer for Linux. If it is damaged, any new software installation will cause this error message.

**Method 1: Reconfigure dpkg Database**

If your package database has become corrupted, reconfiguring it can repair it.

Enter the following command:

```
sudo dpkg ––configure –a
```

This command reconfigures packages that have been unpacked but not necessarily installed. An interruption at the wrong time can cause this database to become corrupt. This is especially helpful if you were running installation and the process was interrupted.

**Method 2: Force-Install the Software**

If Method 1 does not work, you can attempt to fix the dependencies in the package installer.

Enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install –f
```

The –f option means fix-broken. It repairs any broken dependencies in your package manager. Broken dependencies occur when a download is interrupted, or there is a problem with the cached download.

**Method 3: Remove Bad Software Package**

If you know which software caused the errors on your system, you can remove it.

Enter the command and package_name with the name of the software that is causing the problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove ––purge package_name
```

If an old, outdated, or unused package is causing the problem, you can solve the problem by removing unused software packages.

Enter the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Note: Avoid the next 2 options unless all other methods have failed.

**Method 5: Remove Post Files**

If you know the name of the package that is causing problems, you can delete the files manually. The installation files are usually located in the /var/lib/dpkg/info file.

Type in the following command and replace package_name with the name of the broken software.:

```
sudo ls –l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep –i package_name
```

This will generate a list of all references to the software you installed.

You can then remove them by entering:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/package_name.* /tmp
```

This command moves the files to the /tmp directory, where they cannot affect your package manager.

Next, update the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After which you can re-install the broken software again.

**Method 6: Overwrite Package File**

If you know the name of the package that is causing a problem, you can force an overwrite.

Use the following command and replace full_name_of_package with the actual package name:

```
sudo dpkg –i ––force–overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/full_name_of_package
```

Note: If you do not know the actual name of the package, you can search for it with the following command:

```
ls /var/cache/apt/archies/*package_name*
```

Replace package_name with the name of your software. This should return any instances of that package name. Note the exact filename, and type it into the previous command.